# How to typecast NSManagedObject class to Any to create a BehaviorRelay object in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift, behaviorrelay

I have an Entity called 'CartItem' (`NSManagedObject` class) in my coredata datamodelid. Wanted to change Variable to BehaviorRelay in RxSwift, but I get a compile time error stating "`[Any] is not convertible to CartItem`". How do I change Variable to BehaviorRelay?

```
var cartItemsArray = BehaviorRelay<CartItem>(value: []) //get error here

//var cartItemsArray: Variable<[CartItem]> = Variable([])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the brackets around `CartItem`.

```
let cartItemsArray = BehaviorRelay<[CartItem]>(value: [])
```

And don't make `cartItemsArray` a var, it should be a let.